# Meaning of "Do Ay understand you tew say thet may _sonn_ .

Tags: meaning, expressions

I'm studying English fiction and don't understand the statement below (which I've put in bold), which I found reading a short story written about 50 years ago by an English author: *[Till September Petronella](http://www.thelondonmagazine.org/till-september-petronella-by-jean-rhys/)* by Jean Rhys.

> "You’re mean," she said to Julian, "and you hate girls really. Don’t
>   imagine I don’t see through you. You’re trying to get me down. But you
>   won’t do it. If you think you’re the only man in the world who’s fond
>   of me or that I’m a goddamned fool, you’re making the hell of a big
>   mistake, you and your mother."
>
> She plucked a hairpin from her hair, bent it into the shape of
>   pince-nez and went on in a mincing voice "**Do Ay understend you tew say
>   thet may sonn—**" she placed the pince-nez on her nose and looked over
>   it sourly "**—with one connection–**"
>
> "Damn you," said Julian, "damn you, damn you."

Context: A young woman is arguing with a man (her close friend) and mocks his mother, who belongs to upper class and lives in countryside. Settings: 1914, somewhere near London.

Can this be read "Do I understand you to say that my son -- with one connection --"?  Though it's not a complete sentence, what does this statement seem to mean?

Comment: In case @koh isn't familiar with British vernacular, "taking the piss" means "mocking" and "toffy" means "upper-class" in this context.